# how to set dictionary if select key is repeats with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using python 3 and I have a dictionary containing some scheduler data. Now I want to set that if a day name repeats in the data list.

here is the case and code :

```
data = [
    {'day': 'Monday', 'full_day': True, 'close_day': False, 'start_time': None, 'close_time': None},
    {'day': 'Tuesday', 'full_day': True, 'close_day': False, 'start_time': None, 'close_time': None},
    {'day': 'Wednesday', 'full_day': True, 'close_day': False, 'start_time': None, 'close_time': None},
    {'day': 'Thursday', 'full_day': True, 'close_day': False, 'start_time': None, 'close_time': None},
    {'day': 'Friday', 'full_day': True, 'close_day': False, 'start_time': None, 'close_time': None},
    {'day': 'Saturday', 'full_day': True, 'close_day': False, 'start_time': None, 'close_time': None},
    {'day': 'Saturday', 'full_day': False, 'close_day': True, 'start_time': None, 'close_time': None},
    {'day': 'Sunday', 'full_day': True, 'close_day': False, 'start_time': None, 'close_time': None}
]
```

as you can see Saturday is 2 times in the data list. the second one is full-day false and close-day true. Now I want that to stay there and the first Saturday object removes from the list.
And this thing with all days which come in the list multiple times.

Comment: Well this is not an actual case. I don't want someone to write some code for me. I just want to know how can we solve such kind of case . is it a set function that can do this job or something else. Because i have tried set function applying on the data object. But that didn't work and return me an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary with `day` as the key for this (using [dictionary comprehension](https://peps.python.org/pep-0274/)):

```
data = list({d['day']: d for d in data}.values())
```

This will keep only the last occurrence of each day.

The above is equivalent to:

```
'''
data_dict will be:
{
   'Monday': {'day': 'Monday', 'full_day': True, 'close_day': False, 'start_time': None, 'close_time': None},
   'Tuesday': {'day': 'Tuesday', 'full_day': True, 'close_day': False, 'start_time': None, 'close_time': None},
   ...
}
'''
data_dict = {}

for d in data:
    data_dict[d['day']] = d

data = list(data.values())
```

`data_dict` is a dictionary of `day`:`data`. So for each `day`, `data_dict` will store its latest entry from `data` (as older entries will be overridden).

Comment: Appreciated man. Can you brief explain how you did this. i can see you have used short hand for loop here and converting end results in list and that's all i understood here. can you also write the alternative brief syntax of this code line.

Comment: I've updated the question with a more explicit version. I suggest reading about dict-comprehensions - very cool and useful thing

Comment: Thank you so much. It was really helpful and It was a smart approach. Appreciated brother.

Answer (score 0):

for-loop will find a saturday you don't need and pop it

```
data = [
{ 'day': 'Monday', 'full_day': True, 'close_day': False, 'start_time': None, 'close_time': None},
{ 'day': 'Tuesday', 'full_day': True, 'close_day': False, 'start_time': None, 'close_time': None},
{ 'day': 'Wednesday', 'full_day': True, 'close_day': False, 'start_time': None, 'close_time': None},
{ 'day': 'Thursday', 'full_day': True, 'close_day': False, 'start_time': None, 'close_time': None},
{ 'day': 'Friday', 'full_day': True, 'close_day': False, 'start_time': None, 'close_time': None},
{'day': 'Saturday', 'full_day': True, 'close_day': False, 'start_time': None, 'close_time': None},
{ 'day': 'Saturday', 'full_day': False, 'close_day': True, 'start_time': None, 'close_time': None},
{'day': 'Sunday', 'full_day': True, 'close_day': False, 'start_time': None, 'close_time': None} 
]

for e,i in enumerate(data):
    if i['day'] == 'Saturday' and i['full_day']:
        data.pop(e)

for i in data:
    print(i)

# {'day': 'Monday', 'full_day': True, 'close_day': False, 'start_time': None, 'close_time': None}
# {'day': 'Tuesday', 'full_day': True, 'close_day': False, 'start_time': None, 'close_time': None}
# {'day': 'Wednesday', 'full_day': True, 'close_day': False, 'start_time': None, 'close_time': None}
# {'day': 'Thursday', 'full_day': True, 'close_day': False, 'start_time': None, 'close_time': None}
# {'day': 'Friday', 'full_day': True, 'close_day': False, 'start_time': None, 'close_time': None}
# {'day': 'Saturday', 'full_day': False, 'close_day': True, 'start_time': None, 'close_time': None}
# {'day': 'Sunday', 'full_day': True, 'close_day': False, 'start_time': None, 'close_time': None}
```

Comment: I believe this is a minimal example. But `data` can have more repetitions for more days. Your code only solves for Saturdays with `full_day` == `True`